# Not enought values to unpack when parsing passwords file

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple login system and keep getting value error on one line

error:

```
File "/Users/davidjohns/Desktop/Loginsystem/hw4.py", line 44, in <module>
    access(option)
  File "/Users/davidjohns/Desktop/Loginsystem/hw4.py", line 30, in access
    login(name,password)
  File "/Users/davidjohns/Desktop/Loginsystem/hw4.py", line 9, in login
    a,b = i.split(",")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

```
for i in file:
         a,b = i.split(",")
         b = b.strip()
         if(a==name and b==password):
             success = True
             break
```

```
granted = False
def grant():
    global granted
    granted = True
def login(name,password):
    success = False
    file = open("passwords.txt","r")
    for i in file:
         a,b = i.split(",")
         b = b.strip()
         if(a==name and b==password):
             success = True
             break
    file.close()
    if(success):
        print("Login Successful")
        grant()
    else:
        print("wrong user name or password")
        
def register(name,password):
    file = open("passwords.txt","a")
    file.write("\n"+name+","+password)
    grant()
def access(option):
    global name
    if(option=="login"):
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        login(name,password)
    else:
        print("Enter your name and password to register")
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        register(name,password)

def begin():
    global option
    option = input("Login or Register (Login,Reg): ")
    if(option!="login" and option!="reg"):
        begin()
        
begin()
access(option)

if(granted):
    print("### USER DETAILS ###")
    print("Username: ",name)
```

Comment: I bet your `passwords.txt` file has a blank line in it.  Either fix `register` to not write blank lines or fix `login` to ignore them.

Comment: Adding to Samwise, the newline may be at the end of the file, and very difficult to find.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the lines in your file does not contain a comma, and therefore is not being split into two values but rather just a single value. You can't unpack a single value to two values. You can fix this in your data file, but really you should just check for it:

```
def login(name,password):
    success = False
    file = open("passwords.txt","r")
    for i in file:

         # New code
         splitLine = i.split(",")
         if len(splitLine) < 2:
             print("Bad line: " + i)
             continue
         # End new code

         a,b = splitLine
         b = b.strip()
         if(a==name and b==password):
             success = True
             break
    file.close()
    if(success):
        print("Login Successful")
        grant()
    else:
        print("wrong user name or password")
```

Comment: Ideally, use `csv.reader` rather than splitting file lines

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sensible advice.  I will note we're also apparently storing passwords and usernames in plaintext in a file though, so probably not the biggest issue here, haha.